# Obtain a substring of a string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, substring

I have a div with the following classes:

```
form-group val-presence-text val-type-pos-int val-length-10 has-success has-feedback
```

I want to get the `10` from the `val-length-10` class name. I've tried various methods, but none seem to work for a dynamic multi-class attribute such as this. In addition, the `10` could be any positive integer and the class could be located anywhere within the group of classes.

Any ideas?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to put it into it's own attribute? $('div').attr('data-val-length');, or is it not in your control?

Comment: In this case, I'm creating a jQuery plugin where the user only needs to add certain classes to the form-group div to activate certain validations. I'm creating this to teach me jQuery, so I'm not very familiar with the data attributes as of yet, but I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @JamieBarker: If you're putting it in a `data` attribute, you should fetch it through `.data('val-length')` instead of `.attr`, but this would be the better way to go, overall.

Comment: @Colin Why is it better if both do the same thing?

Comment: @JamieBarker: Because that's the purpose of the `data` function, to work with `data` attributes. There's lots of ways to do things, and very often there's a better way.

Comment: @ColinDeClue you're not answering the question though. If `$('div').data('stuff')` and `$('div').attr('data-stuff')` return the same thing, what makes one **better to use** than the other?

Comment: @ColinDeClue never mind, I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423383/which-is-better-div-attrdata-stuff-or-div-datastuff/23424446#23424446) and got the answers I was looking for :)

Comment: @JamieBarker: One other thing to consider: If you (or someone else) add something with `.data`, you won't be able to pull it back with `.attr`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
var val_length = $('div').attr("class").match(/val-length-(\d+)/)[1];
```

Comment: Should be noted that this returns `["10"]` rather than `"10"`

Comment: This solution is **TOTALLY** wrong. It will just match any first number in a string. And if the string doesn't contain numbers it will throw a `TypeError` exception.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
var n = (this.className.match(/val-length-(\d+)/) || []).pop();
```

Or in the context:

```
$('[class*="val-length-"]').each(function() {
    var n = (this.className.match(/val-length-(\d+)/) || []).pop();
    console.log(n);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the it is 'val-length' that never changes and just the integer on the end of it, you should be able to do this:

```
//get an array of classes on a specific element
var classList =$('#elementId').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
//loop through them all
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
    //check if any of those classes begin with val-length-
    if (item.indexOf('val-length' === 0) {
       console.log(item.substring(11))
    }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
$("div[class*=val-length-]").each(function() {
    var s = this.className;
    var length = 0;

    $(s.split(" ")).each(function() {
        if (this.search("val-length-") === 0) {
            length = this.substr(11);
        }
    });

    console.log(length);
});
```

It will find the relevant div and pull the value for you.

Comment: This assumes that the class list ends with `val-length-` which it won't if's followed by an integer. Presumably you meant `*=val-length-`

Comment: @RGraham Yes - late in the day and not enough caffeine to help me stay awake.  Thanks for pointing out my schoolboy error :)