# Which jQuery method is better: ".attr('data-thing');" or ".data('thing');"

Tags: jquery, methods

Which one is better:

```
$('div').attr('data-stuff');
```

or

```
$('div').data('stuff');
```

After having a discussion in the comments on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410522/obtain-a-substring-of-a-string-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment35879244_23410522), I'm interested to know which is better to use, if any.

Comment: For me they have the same effect but I prefer `.data('stuff')` why? because it's short to write

Comment: Using `data()` does not include any dom changes so that could be faster... so i will prefer that to `.attr()`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, they don't return the exact same thing right? `attr` returns a string, while `data` returns it as an object.
http://jsfiddle.net/rBtPA/

Comment: @user3008011 you need to use the key like `.data("test")`

Comment: @BatuZet You are correct, I've been using `.data()` only for returning all data so it seems. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Here's a test for 100k divs [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ESGK3/) and appearantly `.attr` is better.

Comment: Both are quite overused. Remember to only use data-attributes for presentation logic. If you want to keep data, use plain old JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking what all people have said into consideration, here is "the answer":

`.data` is better because:

1. it's slightly shorter to type.
2. It can protect you from possible future changes to data structure (although unlikely).

`.attr` is better because:

1. it loads nearly 3 times faster.

I think I will continue using `.attr` myself, but thank you all for this information :)

Comment: Be aware that the performance difference is highly unlikely to ever matter. It's client side (so distributed load) and unless you are doing a lot of processing (in which case I'd question the use of Javascript at all, and you certainly wouldn't use .attr or .data but your own data structures) the performance difference just will not matter. Premature optimization is bad. Always go for cleaner code first.

Comment: This answer is completely nonsense.

Comment: @VSG24 Thank you for your really helpful and insightful comment, and for helping to make SO a better place. LOL. In all seriousness now, this answer is just a summary of the comments placed on the question, so any interested person viewing this page doesn't have to trawl through them.

Comment: @VSG24 Also, given that this answer is over 2 years old now, it's probably now incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

This is edging close to being "too opinion based" but in this case there is actually a solid reason.

Essentially when coding you should allow the library you are working with to do as much of the "heavy lifting" as possible. You should insulate your code from the underlying data as much as possible.

One way to do this is to use the most specific call available. In this case you have a method that already extracts the data and you just tell it the data you need. Using the more generic method to replicate that data extraction behavior should be avoided.

Doing this makes your code slightly shorter. It also makes it safer (for example there is no opportunity to typo 'data-' as 'dota-' or similar) and it means that if there are any fixes or hacks done in the library (for example to work around a browser limitation with a specific browser) then you will benefit from them.

It can also insulate you from future changes in the data structures behind a library, although in this case that's unlikely.

Comment: This sounds like a logical answer to me. Using a specific function in stead of a general one seems more semantic to me.

Comment: Well I was looking for solid fact reasons as to why one is better than the other, and you put forward a solid case. :)