# jQuery: get data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

In my html I have a `span` element:

```
<span class="field" data-fullText="This is a span element">This is a</span>
```

And I want to get the `data-fullText` attribute. I tried these two ways, but they didn't work (the both return `undefined`):

```
$('.field').hover(function () {
    console.log('using prop(): ' + $(this).prop('data-fullText'));
    console.log('using data(): ' + $(this).data('fullText'));
});
```

Then I searched and found these questions: [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute-using-jquery) and [jquery can't get data attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351282/jquery-cant-get-data-attribute-value).
The both's answers are `"Use .attr('data-sth') or .data('sth')"`.
I know that `.attr()` is deprecated (in jquery-1.11.0, which I use), but, however, I tried it.
And it workded!

Can someone explain why?

Comment: `$(this).data('fulltext')` will work as attributes are lower cased. But indeed, you should set it as: `data-fulltext` or `data-full-text`. For the later, then: `$(this).data('fullText')` would work, using camel case syntax

Comment: FYI, `I know that .attr() is deprecated ` attr() is not deprecated, this is the method to use to set/get attribute, not property

Comment: So what I should use - `prop` or `attr`?

Comment: In your case, use `data()` instead but you should rewrite this attribute to use: `data-fulltext="This is a span element"`

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You could use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
$(this).attr('data-fullText')
```

or if you **lowercase** the attribute name:

```
data-fulltext="This is a span element"
```

then you could use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function:

```
$(this).data('fulltext')
```

The `.data()` function expects and works only with lowercase attribute names.

Comment: Great, then all you have to do is lowercase your attribute name because that's how the .data function works and how it expects your attributes to be named.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I didn't now that `data-` should have only lower-case letters :)

Comment: you are not the first and not the last who stuck on undefined data because of the lowercase limitation

Comment: IN CASE ANYONE MISSED DATA- ONLY USES LOWER CASE --- good catch!

Comment: If anyone is interested as to which of these options is best to use, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423383/which-jquery-method-is-better-attr-or-data/23424446#23424446)

Comment: I should warn you that if you change the value using .data('attr', value), you can only retrieve it using .data(), using .attr() will give you the value stored on the DOM only which isn't updated via a call to .data's setter.

Comment: I prefer the syntax:  $(this).data().fulltext.   Often one has multiple data-attributes on an element so it's often useful to create a local variable that points to the data object so that one doesn't have to traverse the object tree each time, e.g. var data = $(this).data();, and then use that local variable in your code to read each property in turn, e.g. var name = data.name, var age = data.age.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Try this:** .attr()

```
  $('.field').hover(function () {
    var value=$(this).attr('data-fullText');
  $(this).html(value);
});
```

**DEMO 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/Jn4V3/

**2. Try this:** .data()

```
$('.field').hover(function () {
    var value=$(this).data('fulltext');
  $(this).html(value);
});
```

**DEMO 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/Jn4V3/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070277/why-jquery-1-9-attr-method-not-deprecated

Comment: This is 2023, and only `.attr()` worked for me. `.data()` was returning an empty Object.

Answer (score 3):

Change IDs and data attributes as you wish!

```
  <select id="selectVehicle">
       <option value="1" data-year="2011">Mazda</option>
       <option value="2" data-year="2015">Honda</option>
       <option value="3" data-year="2008">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="4" data-year="2005">Toyota</option>
  </select>

$("#selectVehicle").change(function () {
     alert($(this).find(':selected').data("year"));
});
```

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ed5axgvk/1/

Comment: The question was about data attributes and nothing to do with selects or any other form of input.

Comment: The example was about data attributes too. Read it again!

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe it would have been clearer if you'd illustrated your answer with the static span in the question, rather than use an input field. That threw me. Sorry.

Comment: This worked for me, and your solution is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
$('.someclass').click(function() {
    $varName = $(this).data('fulltext');
    console.log($varName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".fc-event").each(function(){
  
   console.log(this.attributes['data'].nodeValue) 
  });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='external-events'>
   <h4>Booking</h4>
   <div class='fc-event' data='00:30:00' >30 Mins</div>
   <div class='fc-event' data='00:45:00' >45 Mins</div>
</div>
```