# Jquery .data() method not working when getting html attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, the jquery .data() method is only working when the data is set using jquery. Attempting to retrieve data attributes set in the html results in a return value of null or undefined. Here is my javascript and html.

```
var ico = "<span class='deleteTag'></span>";
var x = "<span class='usertag' data-id='" + ui.item.userid + "'>" + ui.item.label+ " " + ico + "</span>";
$("#" + id + " .userEditor").prepend(x);

$("#" + id + " .userEditor .deleteTag").bind("click",function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr("data-id"))
    alert($(this).parent().data("id"));
    alert($("#testdivv").data("hola"));
    $(this).parent().data("yolo","swag");
    alert($(this).parent().data("yolo"));                                     
    // $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="#testdivv" data-hola="hello"></div>
    <div id="user1"><div class="userEditor" style="border:1px solid gray;">
        <input style="border:0px;width:600px;" type="text" onKeyUp="if(event.keyCode != 13 && event.keyCode != 40)userSuggest('user1');"/>
    </div>
    <div class="userSuggestions"></div>
    <input name="IDList"  class="hiddenPut" type="hidden" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use `$(element).attr('data-id');` to get a html attribute.

Comment: jQuery's data is more than just reading attributes: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Put the JS code inside `ready` handler: `$(document).ready(function() { your code here });

Comment: This may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23592030/3132718

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: What browser are you using ? Is it HTML5 compatible ?

Comment: Are you sure that `ui.item.userid` has only lowercase letters (however, I suppose that it has only digits)?

Comment: @I didn't understand: I know that works. I'm just trying to understand why data isn't working.

Comment: @Musa: 1.8.4, but since data() works when data is set in jquery itself, that's not the issue

Comment: @Tchi Yuan - I'm on chrome

Comment: @I didn't understand: yes it's only digits

Comment: Are you sure, without any doubt that `$(this).parent()` references the correct span element (the one with class='usertag') ?

Comment: @Tchi-Yuan Yes, because the .attr() method returns the expected value. It's the data method that isn't working.

Comment: I see multiple things which are off in the above code. To begin with, what is `id` in your code? is it `testdivv`? Then your selector `$("#" + id + " .userEditor")` is wrong since `userEditor` is not inside the div `id#testdivv` but it is next to it. Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Krishna id is = "user1". I can't provide a fiddle because I'm pulling data via ajax, which is the part of my code i cut out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seHbL/3/).

It works for me in Chrome.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var id = "editor1";
    var ui = { 
                item: { userid : "user1", label: "some label" }
             };

    var ico = "<a href='#' class='deleteTag'>ClickThisDeleteTag</a>";
    var x = "<span class='usertag' data-id='" + ui.item.userid + "'>" + ui.item.label+ " " + ico + "</span>";

    $("#" + id + " .userEditor").prepend(x);

    $("#" + id + " .userEditor .deleteTag").bind("click",function(){
        $("#answer").html($(this).parent().data("id"));
    });

});
```