# can't dynamically change h3 text using data atribute, jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Need to dynamicaly cha data attribute change h3 text using

```js
$('.partOfMachine').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('thisPart');
  var nPart = $(this).data('namePart');
  $('#textPart').text(nPart);
 }, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('thisPart');
  $('#textPart').text('Модель состовляющих завода');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="machinery">
    <h3 class="text-center" id="textPart">Модель состовляющих завода</h3>
    <a href="recycling.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="recyclingPart" data-namePart="Переработка"></div></a>
    <a href="cutting.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="cuttingPart" data-namePart="Резка"></div></a>
    <a href="aging.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="firstAgingPart" data-namePart="Выдержка сырья"></div></a>
    <a href="moulding.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="blockMouldingPart" data-namePart="Блок-формовочное оборудование"></div></a>
    <a href="expanding.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="expandingPart" data-namePart="Предвспениватели"></div></a>
    <a href="aging.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="secondAgingPart" data-namePart="Выдержка сырья"></div></a>
    <a href="moulding.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="shapeMouldingPart" data-namePart="Фигурно-формовочное оборудование"></div></a>
</div>
```

Need to dynamicaly cha data attribute change h3 text using

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592030/get-data-attribute

Comment: first search, then ask question please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `var nPart = $(this).attr('data-namePart');` or make the attribute name lowercase `data-namepart`, then `$(this).data('namepart')` will work

Comment: Thanks a lot, changed to lowercase and its ok)))

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the html attribute value with jquerys [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function like so :

```
var nPart = $(this).attr('data-namePart')
```