# get the data-* attributes of a tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Instead of using the regular attr() is there a shorthand in jQuery to access all the `data-*` attributs of an element. One which enable me to just specify the name without the `data-` prefix, like **dataset**
`document.getElementById('id').dataset.somename;`

Comment: yes, you can use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/ or https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean..this is something baked into jQuery. For example if you have `<a id='foobar' data-foo='bar' href='..'>foo</a>` you can do e.g. `$('a#foobar').on('click',function() { console.log($(this).data('foo'); });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592030/get-data-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Yes. There is a shorthand to get all the data-* attributes from an element.

To grab a single element's data value (which looked like what you wanted, but I guess it's not..?):

```
$("div").data("name");
```

That would grab the value from `data-name`. Example:

```
<div data-name="Jacob"></div>

$("div").data("name"); //"Jacob"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nhzj3qtk/

---

To grab all the data-* attributes, you can do this:

```
$("div").data();
```

Here's an example for what you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/nhzj3qtk/1/

Comment: Please read the question, he is not asking HOW to get the data attribute. He wants to know how to list ALL data attributes.

Comment: Maybe so, but I think `"... is there a shorthand in jQuery to access all the data-* attributs of an element"` is pretty clear.

Comment: @Martin well his followup sentence sounds like he more specifically wants to grab a specific value, and his example at the very end seems to confirm that.  So my overall takeaway is that his initial "access all the data-\*.." was meant more like "access data-\*..". IOW more "access this stuff in general".  My 2 cents

Comment: @CrayonViolent That was my initial thought as well. After rereading it, I read it as multiple attributes, but still fall back to what I answered with.

Comment: in any case, if OP really wants *all* attributes, calling `.data()` without any parameters will return an object with all `data-*` attributes

Comment: @Snorlax, after your update it's unclear to me if the answer is "no" (as stated) or the answer is "yes"...

Comment: @zed: You are absolutely right. I forgot to edit the top part.