# Access javascript object properties containing keywords?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to access the javascript object property with a keyword in it:

```js
        var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;

        $(document).on("click", 'button.clone', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".clonedInput").clone().insertAfter(".clonedInput:last").attr("id",
                    "clonedInput" + cloneIndex).find("[id], [name] ,[data-valmsg-for]").each(
                    function () {
                        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, cloneIndex);
                        this.name = this.name.replace(/\d/, cloneIndex);
                        this.data-valmsg-for = this.data-valmsg-for.replace(/\d/, cloneIndex);
                    });
            cloneIndex++;
        });
```

But because of the line:

```
this.data-valmsg-for = this.data-valmsg-for.replace(/\d/, cloneIndex);
```

That has:

```
 this.data-valmsg-for
```

It throws an error because "for" in data-valmsg-for is a keyword.
Also when I changed:

```
 this.data-valmsg-for
```

To:

```
this['data-valmsg-for'] = this['data-valmsg-for'].replace(/\d/, cloneIndex);
```

Script throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Also when I changed:

```
 this.data-valmsg-for
```

To:

```
this.setAttribute('data-valmsg-for',this.getAttribute('data-valmsg-for').replace(/\d/, cloneIndex));
```

Script throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
```

And this is my html:

```html
<div id="clonedInput1" class="form-group clonedInput">
            <input id="CompanyId1" name="[0].CompanyId" type="hidden" value="">

            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="NationalCode">کد ملی</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-regex="فرمت کد ملی صحیح نمی باشد" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]{10}$" @*data-val-remote="'کد ملی' is invalid." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.NationalCode,*.initialNationalCode" data-val-remote-url="/Account/IsValidNationalCode"*@ data-val-required="وارد کردن کد ملی اجباریست" id="NationalCode1" name="[0].NationalCode" type="text" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[0].NationalCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="BirthDate">BirthDate</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field BirthDate must be a date." data-val-required="The BirthDate field is required." id="BirthDate1" name="[0].BirthDate" type="date" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="[0].BirthDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You do have to use the `[ ]` notation, and you have to check to see whether the properties exist.

Comment: The problem is not the `for`. The problem is primarily the `-`. `this.data-valmsg-for` means `this.data` *minus* `valmsg` *minus* `for`. *"Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"* means that the property doesn't exist. If the property was just `for`, then `this.for` would work perfectly fine.

Comment: Given that `this` is a DOM element, you are looking for `this.getAttribute('data-valmsg-for')`.

Comment: This is erratically marked as a duplicate by Felix. The OP clearly says that he still has got an error when using [] notation. The so called duplicate only address the issue of [] notation.

Comment: I doubt `data-valmsg-for` is a property on your elements. It's probably am attribute in which case you should use `this.getAttribute( 'data-valmsg-for' );` or `$( this ).attr( 'data-valmsg-for' )`

Comment: Duplicate of  [Get data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23592030/218196).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It throws an error because "for" in data-valmsg-for is a keyword.

No, it throws an error because you are subtracting `for` from `valmsg` from `this.data`. `this.data-valmsg-for` is interpreted as `this.data - valmsg - for`.

It seems the problem you are trying to solve is updating the data property of a DOM element. There are multiple ways to do this. The most basic one is to read the attribute with [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and set it with [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
this.setAttribute(
  'data-valmsg-for',
  this.getAttribute('data-valmsg-for').replace(/\d/, cloneIndex)
);
```

Comment: Or rather, use [`this.dataset.valmsgFor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) :-)

Comment: Those fancy new APIs....

Comment: Script throws this error:Script Uncaught TypeError:
Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Comment: @HamedAz If `getAttribute` returns `null`, then the element doesn't have such an attribute. Since you are selecting elements that either have an `id` attribute *or* a `name` attribute *or* a `data-valmsg-for` attribute, you have to check for every attribute / property, whether it exists or not before you are trying to do something with the value.

Comment: You're right. Thanks