# how to get value of data attribute and use it in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the data attribute value thats on an image and then use that value to set my slider speed, how do I get this value?
I tried the below but console.log returns undefined..

```
var sliderSpeed = $('logo').data('data-speed');

console.log(sliderSpeed);

$('.infinite-slider').infiniteslide({
    'speed': sliderSpeed,
    clone: 10
  });
```

```
<li><img class="logo full-width" src="" data-speed="100"></li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592030/jquery-get-data-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the '.' for `$('.logo')`

```js
var sliderSpeed = $('.logo').data('speed');

console.log(sliderSpeed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><img class="logo full-width" src="" data-speed="100"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

User the `attr` method:

```
var sliderSpeed = $('.logo').attr('data-speed');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sliderSpeed = $('logo').data('speed');
```

The data function by default fetches all data attribute.
To filter a specific data attribute, pass attribute name as parameter to data function.

Answer (score 0):

You dont use correct selector, if you selecting $('logo') jquery is looking for element with tag logo not with class logo.

if you want to select el by class name it should be $('.logo')

to get data-whatever attribute simply use `$('.logo').data('speed')`, you can also getting value using attr `$('.logo').attr('data-speed')`