# How can I get data-id from multiple elements with single onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

as the title says I have multiple buttons which they have data-id. I want to open fancybox modal by getting the clicked buttons data-id. Each element on click will open their own modal.  I can't use class selector because this function is attached to somewhere else, and I know that $(this) here doesn't mean clicked element.

Thank you for your help.

JQuery

```
  function get_cookie_param(){
    function lorem() {
      var dataId = $(this).data("lorem");
      alert(dataId)
      $.fancybox.open({
        src: dataId,
        type: "iframe",
        opts: {
          toolbar: false,
          smallBtn: true,
          iframe: {
            preload: false,
          },
        },
      });
  }
  ...
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="get_cookie_param();" data-lorem="products/camera.html" class="btn-lorem"></a>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592030/jquery-get-data-attribute

Comment: var dataId = $(this).attr("data-lorem"); 
returns undefined

@evolutionxbox unfortunatly

Comment: Try removing the inner `lorem` function? It may have it's own `this`

Comment: but still I can't get the data-lorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function get_cookie_param(ele) {
  var dataId = $(ele).attr("data-lorem");
  alert(dataId);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="get_cookie_param(this);" data-lorem="products/camera.html" class="btn-lorem">Element</a>
```