# jQuery - Each loop to select all items by data attribute, but also dependent on select (option) values

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, attributes, element

I am in the process of building an e-Commerce shop and have hit a small bump in the road for my actual product page. Based on any product options set that would add to the price if selected, I would like to be able to update the price on the page live when these options have been added. I have managed to iterate through every element with a "data-price-effect" attribute attached to them, HOWEVER, when it comes to a **select** element, I would need to check if the item is selected as an **option**, each option has their respective price change attribute of course, but the value would only update to the actual **select** element.

Here is my code upto now:

```
function updatePrice(){
    $('[data-price-effect]').each(function( index ) {
        // do something
    });
}
```

Basic HTML set-up to explain further:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="foo" onchange="updatePrice();" data-price-effect="10.00" />

    <select name="bar" onchange="updatePrice();">
        <option selected value="Item1" data-price-effect="5.00">Item 1</option>
        <option selected value="Item2" data-price-effect="8.00">Item 2</option>
        <option selected value="Item3" data-price-effect="10.00">Item 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I have NO idea how to even logically do this, not even with some huge messy code. Any pointers here from someone more experienced with Javascript?

Comment: You should post your HTML structure too, so people can see what you're working with

Comment: It's literally form elements that have the data attribute, updated question though.

Comment: What is the selection criterion for selecting the `select`?

Comment: @Regent How would I check this during the loop efficiently? There are different elements other than the select that will be checked during this (input, textarea). The value and **onchange** fire is part of the actual **select** element, not the **option** that you are selecting (which has the data attribute attached to it). I would like this to work quite efficiently whilst staying minimal, if possible. I can't find an easy solution to it, if any.

Comment: @void The onchange attached to it will fire my function and I will loop through all elements that have the data attribute, but I need to only grab the ones that are selected in specifically **select** elements, even though this loop will also pass through **input** elements too.

Comment: @DannyVickers outdated inline JS is not good solution from the beginning. Jamie Barker has already started making answer - I hope this answer will be the correct one after corrections.

Comment: I've read this question a few times, and I'm still struggling to understand what you want to do. I've come to the conclusion that, on changing the `<select>` element's chosen `<option>`, you want to add the text-`<input>`'s value to the chosen-`<option>`'s value and update the value of the text-input to that summed value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having "updatePrice()" on each element, you could have a listener for all form elements for the function:

```
var EffectElements = $('form input[data-price-effect], form select');
EffectElements.on('change', function() {
    var PriceEffect = 0;
    EffectElements.each(function() { // Loop through elements
        if ($(this).is('select')) { //if this element is a select
            $(this).children().each(function() { //Loop through the child elements (options)
                if ($(this).is(':selected')) { //if this option is selected
                    PriceEffect += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price-effect'));
                }
            });
        } else {
            PriceEffect += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price-effect'));
        }
    });
});
```

You could then use the `PriceEffect` variable to update your price on the website.

Ultimately it's the [IS](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function doing the dirty work you needed ~_o

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/15r6s42e/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I was thinking of having two separate loops within my function, your method however would only update the price for the single element you have changed, the function needs to run a check on all of them to prevent the price change being added every time that element is updated. Not sure how to go about this, but a loop through all the elements is probably still required.

Comment: You don't need to check every element each time, You could just keep a running total? You could make `PriceEffect` a global variable?

Comment: Actually scratch the last comment, the select value will change every time. /Derp.

Comment: That would be for that single element though? There would be no way to remove the old price change from this variable, it would just keep adding up.

Comment: Thankyou again for helping here, this doesn't seem to even run though for some reason, I added a console.log inside the select loop and got nothing back, not even an error, I'll update if I overcome this.

Comment: That's what happens when you code blind :P. I have updated the answer with a working example, as well as some working code. It wouldn't have been firing for the select because the select doesn't actually have the `data-price-effect` attribute. /Derp

Comment: Well, maybe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4noqo4gw/) is closer to what is really required.

Comment: @Regent Yep I agree, although I would still use an IS on the options just in case you happened to have one option without. Also I would use Attr instead of Data, purely based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423383/which-jquery-method-is-better-attr-or-data) I asked a while back

Comment: @DannyVickers Does the latest iteration(s) help?

Comment: @JamieBarker what do you mean by _to have one option without_? About `.data`: well, it's not noticeably slower there (there are no 100k options), while is a little shorter. Nevetheless, it is not related to question/answer. The real difference between our fiddles **was** that your one added and added `PriceEffect` till infinity.

Comment: @Regent I know which is why I agree'd and +1 your comment :). I mean there could potentially be an option in the select that doesn't have the data attribute for whatever reason. I really am having a brain fart moment today, maybe I should go back to bed o_O

Comment: @Regent Thank you very much both of you, absolutely perfect, works very well now with no issues, code is very efficient and I can definitely re-use for weight calculations etc. Really appreciate it, would up-vote but couldn't remember the details for my old account here, hence why this is a new one.

Comment: @Regent if I could split the 15 rep I earned with you I would. If you want to post your first comment as an answer though I'll happily +1 it :)

Comment: @DannyVickers you're welcome. Well, it's not the most efficient code somewhere, but not far from it.

Comment: @JamieBarker well, our answers will be nearly identical, so there is no reason to post two quite the same answers. The only thing you can do in this situation is to highly unofficially upvote any other my answer :)

Comment: @Regent Whoops my finger slipped ~_o